# apache2 keeps serving old versions of php files

Tags: php, apache, caching, ubuntu

as in the title, this problem still persist, i've configured a virtualHost in apache2(on Ubuntu 12.04 on OVH Dedicated server), i've put a simple index.php in the base directory of my VirtualHost that contains this simple code:

```
<?php
echo "Hello world! ";
?>
```

but when i update my file by adding or removing code, i chek it by accessing the url http://test.xxxxx.ma:8082, the update is not applied, i've cleared  my browser cache, used a new browser, i've cheked if mod_cache is enabled but it's not and i'm sur i'm working on the right directory, the new version of the file index.php is only served after a restart of apache2, my VirtualHost configuration is as follow :

```
<VirtualHost *:8082>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.ovh.net/test"
ServerName test.xxxxx.ma
<Directory "/var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.ovh.net/test">
<IfModule sapi_apache2.c>
    php_admin_flag engine on
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_admin_flag engine on
</IfModule>
AllowOverride All
Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch +Indexes
allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Very probably this is because of caching. Disable any caching and it will refresh right away! Cache examples are APC, memcache or memcached. You can use phpinfo() to find out whether any caching is enabled.

Comment: Its definitely a caching "issue", as in, its working as intended, you just have it configured for a production environment. Check if you have any caching (besides mod_cache) enabled, cause that's definitely it.

Comment: thank you very much, i've user phpinfo() as suggested by Mr "Richard Rodriguez" and i've find out that memcache was aleady installed and configured on the server, as well as apc wich has apc.stat=0, i've commented the memcache section and changed apc.stat=1, Many Thanks to All of you

Answer (score 0):

try adding

```
# Disable Caching for Scripts and Other Dynamic Files
<FilesMatch "\.(pl|php|cgi|spl|scgi|fcgi)$">
    Header unset Cache-Control
</FilesMatch>
```

in a .htaccess file

Comment: How about checking if the caching headers are even set first? In programming (and system administration) for every change there should be some real reason. And "why not" is always a really bad reason.